# GTM - Custom Ecommerce tag

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have just upgraded my site wide GA tags to Universal Analytics to help with cross domain issues, amongst other things. Since I have made the upgrade, all transactions are being tracked as referrals from the payment provider's domain. The payment is taken just before the confirmation page via an iframe which pulls in a page from the payment provider's secure domain. Let's call it secure.provider.com.

Everything was working fine prior to the upgrade, so I have definitely caused the issue.

The only bespoke thing I have is a custom ecommerce tag on the conformation page which I have a feeling is causing the issue, as it's in the traditional GA style:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     var _gaq = _gaq || [];
   var pluginUrl = 
   '//www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ga/inpage_linkid.js';
   _gaq.push(['_require', 'inpage_linkid', pluginUrl]);
   _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-1']);
   _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'xxxxxx.co.uk']);
   _gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Holiday Price Exc", {{SinglePrice}}, 2]);
   _gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 2, "Holiday Extras Rev", {{Total Extras}}, 2]);
   _gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 3, "Departure Airport", {{Departure Airport}}, 2]);
   _gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 4, "Arrival Airport", {{Arrival Airport}}, 2]);
   _gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 5, "Board Basis", {{Board Basis}}, 2]);
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
   _gaq.push(['_addTrans',{{Booking Reference}},{{Category}},{{Total Holiday Price}},'','','','']);
   _gaq.push(['_addItem',{{Booking Reference}},{{Accommodation code}},{{Category}},{{Product Name}},{{Total Holiday Price}},'1']);
   _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);

     (function() {
       var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
       ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
     })();

  </script>
```

Because the data layer is not being used in a standard way I cannot use the default ecommerce tag. Changing the data layer is out of my hands in the near future.

**ISSUE:** If I need to edit the custom ecommerce tag (above) to work with UA, how would I do that?

I have all the autolink domains stuff set up with the UA tags but I am on the verge of rolling the whole thing back as I now have now have no good sales data. I feel like the iframed payment page shouldn't be a problem because it was working with the traditional GA tags.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: ga.js and .push are both classic analytics tagging you will need to change them to use analycis.js for universal analytics

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Sorry, I'm just trying to understand the issue.

Comment: I think I need to amend the custom ecommerce tag to work with the UA tags. I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done with non-standard datalayer is to create a custom html tag with a javascript function that mangled the data into the correct form. Then I pushed a the transformed data and a custom event to the datalayer and fired my transaction tracking on the custom event. That way you could use the UA Tag with GTM which would save you a lot of problems.

However what will probably already help you is to go to the property settings and add the payment providers' domain to the referall exclusion list.

There seems to be no actual cross domain tracking involved (payment might happen on another domain, but you do have no code there) and for the moment it should be possible to mix classic code/Universal Analytics as long as they are not on the same page. However this is not exactly a future-proof solution so you should move to Universal asap.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into setting up the custom event, but ideally I am trying to get the data layer changed into a more standard format.

Comment: Will mark as answered because this does answer the question